# How can I change path qt dll load?

Tags: qt, dll, visual-studio-2019

I want use qt 5.15.2, early i used qt 5.14.2 I tried to start my program in VS2019,but I have problem: **Entry Point Not Found**
I know it was because I see: **BksMtRisk.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\bin\Qt5Cored.dll'.** but I don't know how change this load path dll, help me please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc9bB.jpg)

I have this environment, I have't path with qt5.14.2, what do I must?

Comment: After you hit *OK* on all dialogs (thus saving the changes), you might want to re login.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different version of QT installation at your system and it is defined in system path probably system loads this version of dll. You should check environment parameters, you should set correct installation path in the system path variable.